# Binding to static properties in static class fails

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My public static class Config.cs reads values from Config.xml file.

```
public static class Config
{
    public static string ImagePathBrowse { get; private set; }
    public static bool LoadFromXML()
    {
    //sets ImagePathBrowse
}
```

And I have a login window as a view class, binded to login window view model:

```
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoginWindowViewModel VM = new LoginWindowViewModel();
        this.DataContext = VM;
    }
```

I can bind to properties and use them in/from my view model class easily, but while having this view model class I also want to read some image paths/font types e.t.c. from my Config class. I've tried this in my xaml file:

```
    <Window....
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MeineProject"
    .../>

    <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding Path={x:Static  local:Config.ImagePathBrowse}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="145,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
```

I have tried Mode=OneWay as it is one way binding but it it didn't work either.

I'm still learning WPF/MVMM and read all of the questions around the subject, and everyone else on internet suggested the code above for static linking, but it doesn't work. I get an exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.Data.Binding.Path' threw an exception.' Line number
>   '39' and line position '31'.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, any help/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `Path` set `Source`

Comment: and it works.. I've spent hours trying to find the mistake. Thank you a lot for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Source` instead of `Path`

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Config.ImagePathBrowse}}" .../>
```

`Path` works in current binding context so you need to change source

Answer (score 0):

Since WPF 4.5 you can also use the following syntax to bind to a static property:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=(local:Config.ImagePathBrowse)}" .../>
```